# Http Request throws 'Connection Refused' error from actual device on xamarine

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, httprequest

I'm running the xamarin app on **an actual device** and receiving `Connection Refused` error when making a http request.

Note: the http request works when I use an **emulator**

I've tried the following as the base Url address:
http://127.0.0.1:62597/ ,
http://localhost:62597/

I've also added Require permission for internet from android manifest. solution-> properties-> Android Manifest tab. However one thing I noticed is that when running the app on the device it is not asking for any permission...
I'm quite new to this so any help is much appreciated. Thanks

and this is the StackTrace:

```
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00180] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/ConnectHelper.cs:84 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ea] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:371 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult] creationTask) [0x000a2] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:529 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0003f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:284 
  at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/RedirectHandler.cs:32 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:506 
  at Artvertise.Services.RestHelperExtensions.MakeArtPost[TResponseModel] (Artvertise.Services.ArtClient client, System.String route, System.Object data, Artvertise.Services.ContentType contentType) [0x000c5] in C:\Users\agund\source\repos\Artvertise\Artvertise\Services\RestHelperExtensions.cs:82
```

Comment: `localhost` is alias for `127.0.0.1` that signified the current device. The device request to the device, but your API don't run (I think) on the device. Where is the API running? In your computer in Visual Studio debug?

Comment: Use the IP address of the machine instead of 127.0.0.1 (loopback) or localhost.  On some machines localhost is set to loopback and others it is set to the IP of machine.  So switching from loopback to local host get same bad results.

Comment: The webapp and xamarin forms are under the same solution and I right click on the main solution-> Properties and choose run multiple projects and then select the webapp and android.
When using the emulator I just change the base url to http://10.0.2.2:62597

Comment: @jdweng but web app is running on localhost, What are you refering to by saying "machine address"?

Comment: The IP address of the machine.  The net library gives errors when a client uses the loopback address 127.0.0.1 with a Connect method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the http request works when I use an emulator

This works because the emulator is running on the desktop and use the same network environment with dessktop. When using **localhost** and not **127.0.0.1**, it will find the web server automatically.

However, when running on a physical device, their environment of network are different. You need to specify the IP address of Desktop. Therefore, if using the IP address for emulator, also will work. Such as: `https://192.168.1.15:62597/`

Solution steps:

**First**, you need to make sure your desktop and phone are connected to **the same WiFi** (or any other local network),

**Then** using your **desktop IP address** assigned by the router (not **localhost** and not **127.0.0.1**).

How to find out the IP address of your desktop:

- type into the command line `ipconfig` (Windows)
- there's going to be a bunch of IP's
- try all of them (except the forementioned localhost and 127.0.0.1)

For example, the following screenshot is my IP adress of my desktop:

[image]

Comment: This was bugging my mind all night long and l was thinking the same thing as what you posted.I think your solution will work. I'll try and let you know!  Thanks